# json-rpc with erlang

Tags: json, erlang

I have never used json before, and don't care anything about it except I now have a requirement to access an application through json-rpc.

I have done searches on "erlang json" which returned everything from proposed erlang bifs to mochijson to whatever.  Thing is, I have yet to find any documentation or example using any of this stuff to do what I need to do, which is control another app through json-rpc.  Most of the docs and examples I've seen have dealt with conversions and mappings from erlang data types to json and back.  In fact, docs seem to go so overboard with enthusiasm for representing "language X" terms in json that I've often wondered whether there was something I've missed along the way.  Thus far the topic has failed to stimulate any blood flow towards certain regions of the body, but whatever - it is what it is.

WHAT I DON'T WANT

I DON'T care about javascript, and I DON'T care about doing anything related to json-rpc from javascript or the browser.

WHAT I WANT

To use json-rpc from erlang SERVER SIDE to control an app SERVER SIDE.

At any rate...

1) Can someone point me to some docs and examples showing erlang using a json-rpc library to control or access another app?

2) Can someone recommend a library or libraries to do this?  Since I am currently using yaws (or attempting to), my first choice would probably be yaws since it appears to have some json built-in.  Thing is, the only yaws examples I saw were focused on using javascript code browser side to trigger some kind of json-rpc thing server side, and I don't want to do that.

At any rate, I'll accept the first thing that can do what I want and has documentation showing it being used that way.

Thanks.

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score -1):

> WHAT I WANT
>
> To use json-rpc from erlang SERVER SIDE to control an app SERVER SIDE.

Did you mean There is a json-rpc server implemented with erlang? and you want control an app behind that json-rpc?

Lets say there is a json-rpc server at "https://10.11.1.100:8006/json-rpc/"

And you can use any program language to access that url by http library, for example python's http module with some data for post query or just get query depend on what your json-rpc server provided.

Let's say there is a "Getfruit" and "Putfruit" method provided on json-rpc server for control the back app to load fruit to database.
Then you can use python http library start a get query to "https://10.11.1.100:8006/json-rpc/Getfruit/3", then the server will return a json data contains fruit(ID is 3) detail.

if you want control back app by sending some data to it's database then use post method on "Putfruit" path.

So, this is a simple example for how use json-rpc server.

If I misunderstanding you, if you want how use erlang to control a app through json-rpc server, then just use erlang's http library

Comment: The back json-rpc server is not erlang, it is another language (C++ I believe).  I want to control it using erlang.  I thought I needed a json library to do it.  I will try your http idea - thanks.